# How can I directly link to .dll files using CMake and MinGW as the compiler?

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, mingw, clion

I have a C++ project like this

```
my_project
 |___ app
 |  |__ main.cpp
 |___ include
 |  |__ first.h
 |  |__ second.h
 |___ libs
 |  |__ first.dll
 |  |__ second.dll
 |___ CMakeLists.txt
```

Assume the target name from the **main.cpp** is **my_target**. I would like to link **my_target** with both the DLL libs in **libs** directory. The header files found in **include** directory are the definitions for the .DLL files found in **libs** directory. Can we use .DLL libs directly with C++ code on Windows? If it is possible, then how should we write the CMakeLists.txt for it? I have not found a helpful resource on this topic. Most of the content on the internet either says it is not possible to link to .DLL files or that we have to convert them into .LIB files first.

Comment: Short answer is: You cannot.

Comment: You can not with `msvc`. You can with `MinGW` so the answer may depend on which compiler you are using.

Comment: I have MinGW compiler.

Comment: Just call `target_link_libraries` with absolute path to the library file. E.g. `target_link_libraries(my_target PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/first.dll)`. If your toolchain (compiler) supports linking with `dll`, then it will succeed. If your compiler doesn't support such linkage, then ... you need to chose other compiler or obtain/generate `.lib` files for link with them.

Answer (score 0):

GCC can do it with one of these two invocations. I forgot which is right, but it's one of them.

`gcc file1.c file2.c path\to\library.dll`

`gcc file1.c file2.c -lpath\to\library.dll`